# How to find if element has ancestor based on a variable or parameter (XPath 2.0)

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

The problem I'm trying to solve is to get all elements that contain only a unique text element but at the same time also being able to exclude node trees based on a element name passed as a parameter to the XSLT sheet.

The part to select all the nodes containing only a unique text element that's not empty was relatively easy:

```
$StartNode//element()/text()[normalize-space(.)]/parent::*
```

where `$StartNode` is a Xpath Expression to a specific Element in the XML document.

Now the part I had quite some some problems with, excluding an specific node tree from the results:

so I was hoping for something like:

```
$StartNode//element()/text()[normalize-space(.)]/parent::*[not(ancestor::**$element_to_be_excluded**)]
```

where $element_to_be_excluded is the element name to exclude.

But it's not possible to use a variable on that part of the expression...

So I came up with this solution

```
<xsl:variable name="ancestors_of_current_node" as="xs:string*">
   <xsl:sequence select="$current_parent_node/ancestor::*/name()"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="is_value_in_sequence" as="xs:boolean" select="functx:is-value-in-sequence($exclude_node_local_name, $ancestors_of_current_node)"/>
<xsl:if test="not($is_value_in_sequence)">
    <xsl:call-template name="dataElementMap">
       <xsl:with-param name="node_item" select="$current_parent_node"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:if>
```

where functx:is-value-in-sequence is:

```
<xsl:function name="functx:is-value-in-sequence" as="xs:boolean" xmlns:functx="http://www.functx.com">
  <xsl:param name="value" as="xs:anyAtomicType?"/>
  <xsl:param name="seq" as="xs:anyAtomicType*"/>
  <xsl:sequence select="$value = $seq"/>
</xsl:function>
```

Now the question is, it's there a more elegant way to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance for any hint.

Regards
Vlax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of doing (which doesn't work due to the variable, as you mention)

```
$StartNode//element()/text()[normalize-space(.)]
   /parent::*[not(ancestor::$element_to_be_excluded)]
```

Could you try this instead, to check the ancestor's name?

```
$StartNode//element()/text()[normalize-space(.)]
   /parent::*[not(ancestor::*[local-name() = $element_to_be_excluded])]
```

Answer (score 3):

**If `$element_to_be_excluded` is just the element's name, use**:

```
$StartNode//element()
             [text()[normalize-space(.)]]
                [not(ancestor::*/name() = $element_to_be_excluded)]
```

**If `$element_to_be_excluded` is a sequence of one or more elements, use**:

```
$StartNode//element()
             [text()[normalize-space(.)]]
                [not(ancestor::* intersect $element_to_be_excluded)]
```

**Explanation**:

1. The annecessary `parent::*` is eliminated.
2. If the element name is given, we add an additinal predicate that is `true()` only when the set of names of the ancestors of the selected element doesn't contain the specific name contained in `$element_to_be_excluded`.
3. If `$element_to_be_excluded` contains a sequence of one or more elements, we add an additional predicate that is `true()` only if the selected element isn't one of the elements contained in `$element_to_be_excluded`.

**Do note that in both cases a single XPath expression can  be used** to select the wanted elements -- it isn't necessary to use any XSLT instructions at all.

Comment: +1 for suggesting an abbreviation by eliminating "parent::*", although the second option doesn't seems to work... Thxs! You rock guys!

Comment: @Vlax: The second solution is for the case when `$element_to_be_excluded` contains the real element -- not just its name. It can be used to exclude more than one element's subtree.

Comment: :I got that, but when I test it in XMLSpy 2011 with the following construct:
$StartNode//element()
             [text()[normalize-space(.)]]
                [not(ancestor::* intersect ns0:MyExcludedNode)]
it doesn't seems to do anything.
It should work just for one literal element also, right?

Comment: I got the problem I had either to use the full xpath to the element, like: [not(ancestor::* intersect /ns0:MyRoot/ns0:MyExcludedNode)] or the wildcard selector "//" [not(ancestor::* intersect //ns0:MyExcludedNode)] to get it to work.
Intersect doesn't seems to work on isolated elements.

Comment: @Vlax: The problem is that the relative expression `ns0:MyExcludedNode` is evaluated off the context-node -- and the context node hasn't any `ns0:MyExcludedNode` children. That is -- the second argument to `intersect` in your expression, is the empty node-set. You must specify as the second argument of `intersect` an XPath expression that selects your excluded node -- not just its name.

Answer (score 2):

I would always write stuff like `<xsl:variable name="foo"><xsl:sequence select="someExpression"/></xsl:variable>` as `<xsl:variable name="foo" select="someExpression"/>`. I am not good at making suggestions without seeing an input sample but I suspect instead of using a named template and those two variables  and the `xsl:if` wrapping a `call-template` the code could be written using a template in a mode e.g.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select=".[not(ancestor::*[local-name() eq $exclude_node_local_name])]" mode="m1"/>
```

with your named template `dataElementMap` being replaced by e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="*" mode="m1">...</xsl:template>
```

(or perhaps some more specialized  match pattern).